# ORDER Day in a Week

Tags: php, mysql

I have table named timetable which consists Day in it. The data that enter are randomly such as monday friday tuesday and so on. Therefore i want to pull out to php in order starting from monday tuesday and so on.

```
 ORDER BY FIELD(<fieldname>, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY');
```

i found out code above is used to solve the problem of mine. But somehow i didn't understand how to use it and what its mean by FIELD and fieldname.

is it suppose to be write like this?

```
   SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE NoStudent = '".$NoStudent."' Order By Day ('Monday', .......);
```

please help me. Thank you

Comment: use `field()` as `ORDER BY FIELD(Day,'Monday','Tuesday')`

Comment: You just need to put `ORDER BY FIELD(Day, 'Monday', ...)`. `FIELD` is part of the command syntax as opposed to a placeholder

Comment: `Order by Field( Day, 'Monday', 'Tuesday' ..... )`

Comment: There's an excellent explanation of how it works here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/109126/26769

Comment: Thank you all of you for the explanation. It WORK!. thank you so much everyone.

Answer (score -1):

```
ORDER BY
     day ASC
```

use this may be It will help you